# JQuery Mobile: Using default theme in addition to the custom themes

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have created [custom themes](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) for my JQuery mobile app. While I'm using the custom theme in most areas of my app, I'd like to use the default theme for the navbar in footer. I just can't find how this is possible, whether I provide a data-theme attribute or not, it always uses my custom theme for styling it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't modify the global swatch and assign an unused swatch in your data-theme attribute and it should work.

Comment: I haven't modified the global swatch, and per your suggestion, I assigned a data-theme="z" (that I don't have) to the navbar, but it's not picking up the default theme.

Comment: ThemeRoller does only include swatches that you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded the correct JQM files, there is a css-version with a theme and one without a theme.

Comment: I believe I have the right JQM files, because when I remove the reference to my custom theme and don't specify any swatch, I get the default look and feel.